# Difficulty saving and storing

Tags: java, android

I am trying to save and store data in an android app using java. At the moment the data will not save and it causes my app to crash. Can anyone make any suggestions to my code? Part of my page includes a total budget and I am difficulty storing and saving the total budget.

```
         public class Summary extends Activity implements TextWatcher, View.OnClickListener
          {
         DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("£0.00");
         int noOfGifts, giftsPurchased;
         double cost;
        EditText budgetEntered;
        double savedBudget = 0;
        String budgetString;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
       {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.summary);

     budgetEntered = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.s2TotalBudget);
     budgetEntered.addTextChangedListener(this);

      Button saveBudget = (Button) findViewById(R.id.s2ViewList);
     saveBudget.setOnClickListener(saveButtonListener);
     if(savedBudget != 0)
      {
     saveBudget.setText(budgetString);
      }

    Bundle passedInfo = getIntent().getExtras();
     if (passedInfo != null)
     {
     cost = passedInfo.getDouble("cost");
     noOfGifts = passedInfo.getInt("noOfGifts");
     giftsPurchased = passedInfo.getInt("giftsPurchased");
     }

    Button logoutButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.s2LogoutButton);
     logoutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
     {
     public void onClick(View view)
     {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Summary.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
     }
     });

     Button viewList = (Button) findViewById(R.id.s2ViewList);
    viewList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
     {
     public void onClick(View view)
     {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Summary.this, GiftList.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
     }
     });

     String [][] summary = {{"Number of Presents to buy:   ", (noOfGifts + "")},
          {"Number of Presents bought:", (giftsPurchased + "")},
          {"Cost:                      £", (cost + "")},
          {"Budget:                    £", "50"}};



     String passedBudget=null;

     //convert totalPresents to double from String
     String tempPresents = summary[0][1];
    int presents = Integer.parseInt(tempPresents);

  //convert presentsBought to double from String
  String tempBought = summary[1][1];
  int presentsToBuy = Integer.parseInt(tempBought);



    //Number of presents
    TextView s2PresentResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.s2PresentsResult);
    s2PresentResult.setText(summary[0][1]);

    //Number of presents to buy
    TextView s2PresentsBuyResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.s2PresntsBuyResult);
    s2PresentsBuyResult.setText((noOfGifts - giftsPurchased) + "");


     Bundle passedId = getIntent().getExtras();
     if (passedId != null)
     {
     passedBudget = passedId.getString("Enter Budget");
     }


    //EditText s2TotalBudget = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.s2TotalBudget);
    //s2TotalBudget .addTextChangedListener((android.text.TextWatcher) this);
    //s2TotalBudget .setText(passedBudget, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);


    //Number of people
    //TextView s2TotalBudget = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.s2TotalBudget);
    //s2TotalBudget.setText("Enter budget");




    //Number of people
    TextView s2TotalCost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.s2TotalCost);
    s2TotalCost.setText(df.format(Double.parseDouble(summary[2][1])));

    //Output if over or under budget
    TextView s2CalculateOverBudget = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.s2CalculateOverBudget);

    //convert totalCost to double from String
    String temp = summary[2][1];
    double totalCost = Double.parseDouble(temp);

    //convert totalBudget to double from String
      String tempTwo = "14";
    double totalBudget = Double.parseDouble(tempTwo);


       if((totalCost>totalBudget)&&(totalBudget!=0))
      {
       s2CalculateOverBudget.setTextColor(Color.rgb(209,0,0));
       s2CalculateOverBudget.setText("You are over budget");
      }
       else if(totalBudget==0){
       s2CalculateOverBudget.setText("");
      }
      else {
       s2CalculateOverBudget.setText("You are within budget");
      }


      }

         public View.OnClickListener saveButtonListener = new View.OnClickListener()
         {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v)
       {
       if(budgetEntered.getText().length()>0)
     {
          budgetString = budgetEntered.getText().toString();


     }
      }
    };



        public void onClick(View v)
     {

     }

    @Override
         public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
        {

           }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
    {

     }

    @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
  {
```

Comment: "_it causes my app to crash_" Post your logcat output and indicate which line is causing the crash (which you can get from logcat output). And **please** correctly indent your code. It makes debugging soooo much easier.

Comment: What does the logcat say?

Comment: All the errors and logs that your app generates, if you are using eclipse you can view it by going to Window->Show View->Other->Logcat

Answer (score 0):

this it the best way to store and load value in Android:

- save values: (put this where you want to save the values, for example in the onStop or onPause method. Or, in your case, in the onClick method)

  `SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
  editor.putInt("testValue", value);
  editor.commit();`
- load values:

  `SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
  value = settings.getInt("testValue", defValue);`

Comment: where do I place the load values?

Comment: @HawkeDamian you can place it wherever you want to load the variable. For example in the onCreate method